# How to get the response body from 400 status php request

Tags: php

I know I could use cURL but I am working on a server that I am not allowed to use cURL.

So my question is this: I am using `file_get_contents` to get the response body of a request that is returning status `400`. With `$http_response_header` I can get the headers of the response, HOWEVER for some reason PHP is not displaying the RESPONSE BODY!

When it returns `200` status, `file_get_contents` returns the respose body, however with `400` status it's not returning the response body. How can I retrieve that?

Comment: 400 means a you've sent a bad request, there isn't a body to retrieve.

Comment: How should we know why the code you haven't shared with us is creating an HTTP request which the server you are sending it to (also a secret, as is the server side code it runs) considers to be invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `4xx` [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) mean "Client error".

More specific, the meaning of the [`400` status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) is **"Bad request"**. This means the HTTP request is malformed and the server (or the server-side script that processes it) does not understand it.

The documentation of [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) explains:

> The function returns the read data or `FALSE` on failure.

A status code different than `200` is a failure.

---

There is a way to get the body of the request instead of `FALSE` on errors. All you have to do is to create a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), configure it to [ignore the HTTP errors](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) and pass it as the third argument to [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$url = 'http://localhost/';

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true,
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

`$data` now contains the body of the response but you have to parse [`$http_response_header[0]`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) to know if the request was successful or not.

Anyway, a status code of `400` means an error in the code that issues the request; you should fix the request (probably you submit a body).

Comment: It has a response, if I open it in my chrome browser it shows the body. I know it's not common but this API that I am using for some reason they provide the error details in the body.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @Samul the original answer was downvoted for good reason; it was not good enough. I read the docs, wrote some code and updated the answer. I'm glad it helped you; I have also learned these things writing it.